# Emails Validations on Ruby on Rails giving 'We're sorry but something went wrong' errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am trying to make some email validations on my project by using a series of ''validates'' on my email model.

For example, I made a regex validation for standard email format. It works just fine when I type a standard email format such as ''xxxxx@something.com'' it adds to the database just fine.

But when I try to add an email with the wrong format, ex: "aaaaaaaa" (which worked before the validation) It redirects me to the red error screen message, "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

The server gives that

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

<%= f.submit "Save Email", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  app/views/emails/_form.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_emails__form_html_erb__3126426570893469508_45764920'

  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

I discorved that if I remove the

```
  <div>
    <%= hidden_field :site, :id, value: @site.id %>
  </div>
```

Line of code in the add email form, It validates correctly and it displays the correct error message, but then, without the hidden value tag, It won't add emails.

UPDATE: I got one problem fixed by using a ''f.email_field'' instead of a ''f.text_field''. But when I try to leave the field blank, still get the same errors.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. appreciate it.

Comment: What does `@site` represent?

Comment: @site is a model that ''has_many :emails'', emails belong to a site.

Comment: a `site` then is not created with this form right, you're just using this for the association?  Is this error in production, because that error is very heroku-esk?

Comment: You're right, it is not created with this form. Actually, I am running locally.. It does sound like herokuish thou, lots of simmilar threads relating this to heroku on stackoverflow, but I am not using heroku.
Yes, just for association

Comment: Can I see the form you've created to submit the emails and the controllers `create` action?

Comment: Just added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's used a nested form here.

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="span6 offset3">    
    <%= form_for(@email) do |f| %>
      <% if @email.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@email.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this email from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :address %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :address %>
      </div>
      <%= f.fields_for :site do |site| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :site, value: @site.id %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <section class="buttons">
        <%= f.submit "Save Email", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", back_path(single: true), method: :get, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      </section> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried  that Anthony and it gave me

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:44:in `[]'
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:44:in `create'

Comment: Can you actually print somewhere in your html, this: `<%= @site.id %>` what does that show?

Comment: It is an integer, value = 5

Comment: Unfortannely still getting the same errors, and using the nested form, I am no longer able to add emails like I can using the form I submitted.
 
Unpermitted parameters: site
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:44:in `create'

Comment: What is on line 44 in the emails_controller?

Comment: Also, you can remove this:  `@email.site = Site.find(params[:site][:id])` and simply do something like:  `@email = Email.new(email_params, site: site_params)`  and then define `site_params` at the bottom of your controller

Comment: line 44 is exactly @email.site = Site.find(params[:site][:id])

I defined site_params like this:
def site_params
      params.require(:site).permit(:atribute, :atribute2, :atribute3, :atribute4)
  end

Well, It stopped giving the 'We're sorry errors, something went wrong errors' !!!

Comment: But, it just displays a blank page now.. and the server error changed from error 500 to 400.. it says:

Unpermitted parameters: site
Unpermitted parameters: site
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: site):
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:116:in `site_params'
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:45:in `create'

Does it mean, it cannot find the site which I am trying to add emails to?

Comment: I got one problem fixed by using a ''f.email_field'' instead of a ''f.text_field''. But when I try to leave the field blank, still get the same errors.